# Cannot read property "width" of undefined (Bitmap)

Tags: javascript, html, bitmap, stage, createjs

I have a problem adding a bitmap image to the stage.
This is the code:

```
this.rewind_btn= new createjs.Bitmap(images.rewind_btn);
this.rewind_btn.setTransform(twixjs.Frontend.WIDTH/2 + this.rewind_btn.image.width,twixjs.Frontend.HEIGHT - this.rewind_btn.image.height);
this.stage.addChild(this.rewind_btn);
```

The compiler says that "this.rewind_btn" is undefined.
I am sure that this should work because I added other buttons to the stage the same way. The PNG's are in the same folder so the path to the image is not wrong.
I hope you can see the error in my code.

Thank you for yor time and help

Comment: twixjs.Frontend.WIDTH and twixjs.Frontend.HEIGHT are my canvas dimensions: 1920 and 1080

Comment: From your code it looks like `this.rewind_btn.image` is undefined and not `this.rewind_btn`. Can you validate if that is the case?

Comment: Looks like `new createjs.Bitmap(images.rewind_btn)` loads image asynchronously. In this case you need to wait for image loading completion event to get its width and height.

Comment: What do you have in `images.rewind_btn`? It's a string containing URL or it's image element already?

Comment: the compiles show this error: "this.rewind_btn.image is undefined".
yes images.rewind_btn is the id for the image path